# Prestashop - How to sent email notification when customer subscribed to the out of stock product?

Tags: php, notifications, prestashop

I have used `Mail::Send()` function to send an email, but it does not work, why?

File /mailalerts/controllers/front/actions.php:
https://github.com/PrestaShop/mailalerts/blob/master/controllers/front/actions.php

In `processAdd()` function, before `if ($mail_alert->add() !== false)` I have added this:

```
if ($mail_alert->add() !== false) {
        die('1');

            $product_name = Product::getProductName($id_customer);
            $shop_email = 'my-email-for-test@email.com';
            $shop_name = Configuration::get('PS_SHOP_NAME');
            $dir_mail = dirname(__FILE__).'/../../mails/';
            $template_vars = array(
                '{customer_email}' => $customer_email,
                '{product_name}' => $product_name
            );

            Mail::Send(
                $id_lang,
                'new_oos',
                Mail::l('New request of product', $id_lang),
                $template_vars,
                (string)$shop_email,
                null,
                (string)$shop_email,
                (string)Configuration::get('PS_SHOP_NAME', null, null, $id_shop),
                null,
                null,
                $dir_mail,
                false,
                $id_shop
            );

    } else {
        die('0');
    }
}
```

How to send an email to me?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not configured mail setting in your prestashop. 
To send email from Prestashop, you have to configure SMTP by clicking on  Advanced Preferences -> E-Mail.

A form will be open where you have to enter this :

```
Server: smtp.gmail.com (if you uses gmail)

Username: your gmail id

Password: your gmail password

Encryption: SSL

Port: 465
```

Comment: Mail settings are configured. This is not the problem.
P.S: Email templates (new_oos.html and new_oos.txt) added to the mailalerts/mails/en/ folder.

Comment: then, you may define your code in ActionProductUpdate hook function.

Comment: I don't understand. For what? and how to do that?